# Function notation $f(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: notation

$ U:=\{f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R} : f(\mathbb{R}) \subset [0,1]\}$
$ V:=\{f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R} : f(\mathbb{Z}) =\{0\}\ \}$

I am a little confused by the notation $f(\mathbb{R})$ and $f(\mathbb{Z})$ and to be sure I'd like confirmation/correction. I am assuming that it means that $U$ is the set of functions for which the output values are contained in $[0,1]$ for all real input, such as $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, x\mapsto \frac{1\ +\ \sin x}{2}$ or $f\equiv1  $. $V$ is the set of functions for which output is $0$ for all integer input, such as $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}, x\mapsto \sin \pi x$ or  $f\equiv 0$.

Comment: You are correct. In general the set $f(A) = \{f(x): x\in A\}$ is the image of $A$ under $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are completely right.

More generally if $f \colon X \to Y$ is any map, then for $Z \subseteq X$ we write in some abuse of notation $f(Z)=\{f(z) \mid z \in Z\}$

Comment: For what it's worth, [sometimes people write this as $f[Z]$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Image_of_a_subset) to avoid [abuse of notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_notation) (note that $f(Z)$ looks like $f$ evaluated at $x = Z).$

Comment: Ah, actually, I have never seen this notation but it makes perfectly sense.